How do I clear my Python interpreter cache while executing with pybind11?
I want to embed a Python interpreter in my C++ project using the pybind11 embedded interpreter.
During runtime, Python modules from different locations can be loaded and deleted.
To achieve this, I used importlib to refresh my Python cache. However, the cache remains unchanged, and if I try to load a module with the same name but from a different location, the old module is still loaded.
Thanks for your help.
i tried this small example
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

void addModulePath(const std::string &module) {
    auto sys = py::module::import("sys");
    auto importlib = py::module::import("importlib");
    auto path = sys.attr("path");
    py::print(path);

    path.attr("append")(module);
    importlib.attr("invalidate_caches")();
    py::print(path);
}

void deleteModulePath(std::string& module) {
    auto sys = py::module::import("sys");
    auto importlib = py::module::import("importlib");

    auto path = sys.attr("path");
    py::print(path);
    path.attr("remove")(module);
    importlib.attr("invalidate_caches")();
    py::print(path);

}

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(changeModule, m) {
    m.def("add_module", &addModulePath, "add module path");
    m.def("delete_module", &deleteModulePath, "delete module path");
}

int main() {

    constexpr auto test1Path = "/tmp/test1";
    constexpr auto test2Path = "/tmp/test2";

    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    py::module_ module = py::module_::import("changeModule");

    module.attr("add_module")(test1Path);

    auto test = py::module_::import("test");

    test.attr("test")();
    module.attr("delete_module")(test1Path);

    module.attr("add_module")(test2Path);

    test = py::module_::import("test");
    test.attr("test")();
    return 0;

}

the folders test1 and test2 does both contain a file called "test.py"
which prints its folder name.
I don't want to restart my interpreter.

What version of Python? Looks a bit like https://bugs.python.org/issue45703

What are you trying to accomplish by loading modules with the same name, but different code? In anything more than a toy problem this could lead to bugs where module foo holds a reference to version 1 of test and module bar holds a reference to version 2 of test. Just because you've deleted a module from sys.modules does not mean it is no longer accessible in the interpreter. Have you tried just adding /tmp to sys.path and importing test1.test and test2.test?

Oh, invalidate_caches() isn't enough to load new source code of a module that has already been imported. If a module exists in sys.modules, then that module is always used in preference to loading the module from disk. You need to either delete the module from sys.modules or use importlib.reload(mymod). reload() preserves the globals of the module. So names that were present in the old source, but not the new source will be preserved.

@DanMašek I use Python 3.12.4

@Dunes Thanls for your comments.
you are right with the modules and this is a toy example.
But this bug can also be reproduce in my bigger project. The idea is that you can call python scripts on an embedded linux with a scheduled executer (eg. each 1 sec).
The script can be changed during this execution. Because of the python caching system it will still execute the script without changes.
Using reload() only reloads the imported module not submodules of it... Is there any recursive reload?

Generally you can't reload extensions at all. And lots of things (e.g. Numpy) will just crash if you try

Do these folders contain only one source file? Because if it's just one source file that's changing then why not use exec()? Why is it important that you do not have a separate interpreter per source directory?
